# IIS 7.5 SSL Redirect

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, redirect, 301-redirect

I had a standard website hosted on a server I have full control over - www.domain.com. I recently purchased an SSL certificate for this domain in preparation for accepting credit cards and am looking to have all requests redirect to https://www.domain.com. For the most part, the rule I created (see below) works fine - if I type in http://www.domain.com it'll redirect to https://www.domain.com. The problem I have is if I go to an inner link, such as http://www.domain.com/folder/page.aspx, I get a 404 because the only binding ties to HTTPS. How can I make a redirect rule that says any request for www.domain.com gets sent to HTTPS, but retain the original folder/page structure that was requested? So, going to http://www.domain.com/folder/page.aspx sends me to https://www.domain.com/folder/page.aspx. I'd prefer if query string values also stayed intact.

Here is my current rewrite rule:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving it on my own - I did a combination of two different rules (one to rewrite http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com where the cert is linked to) and another to just redirect all HTTPS requests and it seems to be working perfectly. Here is the relevant config entry:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can take the entire URL with you if you configure redirects within IIS, if you use the attribute **appendUrlTrail="true"**. Maybe you could append it to the  Tag. I'm not sure whether it is working or not :-)

Comment: I can't seem to find any reference to that tag on Bing, Google or doing an MSDN search directly. Where does it go?

Comment: Neither did I. But I thought it was this attribute. I will have a look to the system on monday and tell you the exact configuration.